# Dense subspaces of the space $L^p(0,T;X)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Given a Banach space $X$ and $1\leq p<\infty$, let's define the space $L^p(0,T;X)$ as the set of all strongly measurable functions $f:(0,T)\mapsto X$ such that 
$$\int_0^T\Vert f\Vert_{X}^pdt<\infty$$
(with the usual modifications when $p=\infty$). I'm looking for dense subspaces of $L^p(0,T;X)$; for instance, we konw that for usual Lebesgue space $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$. Are there similar results for the space $L^p(0,T;X)$?
In particular I would like to regularize a function in $L^p(0,T;X)$ in time.

Comment: On page 199 [this script](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6A.pdf) you can find some examples and statements about Bochner integrable functions (what you are looking at). For example simple functions are dense, also functions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \phi_(t)$, $c_i \in X, \phi_i \in C^{\infty}_c(0,T)$.